# Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=eocribin.netne.net/FetchUserData.php

Tags: android, server, database-connection, host

Getting the error and I've no idea why I've been looking at it for hours and I feel like it's something basic I'm missing Can someone please have a look and see what it might be?

```
public class ServerRequests {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
        public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://eocribin.netne.net";
```

I feel like I have labelled the host in the above part to be used as a variable later on but it only registers this as the path

```
    public ServerRequests(Context context) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    }

    public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user,
                                          GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallBack).execute();
    }

    public void fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallBack).execute();
    }

    /**
     * parameter sent to task upon execution progress published during
     * background computation result of the background computation
     */

    public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallBack;

        public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallBack = userCallBack;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                    + "/Register.php");

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I think that you are missing "http://" from `path=eocribin.netne.net/FetchUserData.php`

Comment: Figured it out using that i thought I already had it in but obviously not thanks

Comment: Great! I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing "http://" from `path=eocribin.netne.net/FetchUserData.php`